# Align 3x3 grid relatively to the full viewport height without offset

Tags: html, css, flexbox, materialize

Well, I have grid that's 3x3 dimension, also I'm using CSS framework - **[materializecss](http://materializecss.com)** and I can't reach my goal which title says or this:

[image]

Their documentation [**says**](http://materializecss.com/footer.html):

> Note: We use flexbox to structure our html so that the footer is always on the bottom of the page. It is important to keep the structure of your page within the 3 HTML5 tags: `<header>, <main>, <footer>`

I did it. Also did just add `height: 100%, min-height: 100%` for **html**, **body** and it doesn't help at all. Thanks!

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  color: #eb6a45;
  background-color: #88ba93;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10vw;
  padding-bottom: 10vw;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #48a089;
  color: #fefda5;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out background-color, 0.3s ease-in-out color;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: #063328;
  color: #484848;
}


}
```

```html
<header>

</header>

<main>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
    <div class="item b"><img height="100" width="100" src="#" /></div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Here is fiddle: [**ctrl + click**](https://jsfiddle.net/eeeek/2wjh35ne/)

Comment: sorry, don't understand. what exactly do you mean *align it relative to the viewport height* - can you make a picture of what you're looking for or describe what's happening now and what should happen instead?

Comment: what do you mean by aligning to viewport, do you want to have three vertical and three horizontal items at once ?

Comment: wanna make this boxes be responsive, like they react from width, but do it also for height - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hGDa.jpg

Comment: Do you mean you're trying for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/2wjh35ne/1/

Comment: @StuFurlong yes, indeed! Thanks m8!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the updates I made:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wjh35ne/1)

HTML:

- Removed inline width/height off of the images

CSS:

Change html/body min-height to height and add border-box:

```
html, body {
    height:100vh; // Force 100vh height instead of making it a minimum
}
```

Change `<main>` and `<header>` to have percentage heights:

```
header { height:10%; } // Make header 10% of document
main { height:90%; } // Make main 90% of document
```

Add max width/height to images:

```
img { max-width:100%; max-height:100%; }
```

Added a height to the item and changed the padding to 10px:

```
.item {  
    box-sizing:border-box; // Border box fix for padding
    height:33%;  
    padding:10px; 
}
```